# Ios location service background issue

Tags: ios, core-location

In my iOS app I turned on location services in background and also set on always. I also set up region monitoring for every 500 meters so if iOS kills my app in background then it will wake up using region monitoring. 
But I found one major issue in updating location. I disabled location services of iOS and re enable it, my app is still in background but it's location icon showing disable and other app which is not even in background shows enable. Please see attached screenshot.
If any one knows about this then please guide me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have wrong concept, the arrow unfilled means that the app is using geofences, if you scroll to the bottom in that list you can read the legend as you can se in this screenshot

[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: ok you are right, I added region monitoring in the app for every 300 meters. But in my above given situation if i am travelling upto 2 kms and nothing happen in my app. Means locationDidUpdate not calls. If i will open app and minimise it again then it works fine again. 
I am travelling with my macbook with attached debugger with wait for executable to launch for testing regions.

Comment: @AmritTrivedi did it launch your app in the background?! I don't think it would. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
In app delegate.m,

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication )application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary )launchOptions
{

    [self setUpLocationManager];
 return YES;
}
#pragma mark - CLLocationManager Delegate
-(void)setUpLocationManager
{
    LocationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    LocationManager.delegate=self;
    LocationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [LocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    [LocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager )manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation > *)locations
{
    CLGeocoder *GioCoder=[[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

    [GioCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:LocationManager.location completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark >  Nullable placemarks, NSError * Nullable error)
    {
        if (error !=nil)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            CLPlacemark *place=[placemarks lastObject];

            NSLog(@"%@",place);

            NSString *Path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"countries" ofType:@"json"];
            NSError *Error;
            NSData *JsonData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:Path options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:&Error];
            NSMutableArray *DataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            if (Error==nil)
            {
                NSError *err;
                DataArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
            }

            for (int i=0; i<DataArray.count;i++)
            {
                if ([[[DataArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"code"] isEqualToString:place.ISOcountryCode])
                {
                   // Insert your code here

                    [LocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager )manager didFailWithError:(NSError )error
{
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
    {
        NSLog(@"Location not enabled in your device");
    }
    else
    {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Reiner said in his answer, your understanding is wrong. If you have an **empty** purple arrow it means your **geofence is set correctly.**

If another app is staying **filled** purple. It could be because of multiple reasons:

- It has `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` set to `false` and is always tracking.
- It has `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` set to `true` but hasn't yet paused long enough at a location to trigger a pause which would technically turn that **filled** purple into either gray or empty purple (which means the app is continuing tracking using significant location changes or regionMonitoring or visits monitoring)

AFAIK if you region is setup for 500meters then it's better to use SignificantLocation Changes. Because you can use cellTower information. For regionMonitoring app turns it's location Tracking on and off every few minutes to make sure it's been exited the app or not.

**VERY IMPORTANT NOTE**

Apple documents on this are very confusing. It took me a whole week to figure it out!

Region Monitoring or significant location Tracking or visit Monitoring will only launch app in the background if and only if your app was **terminated**. If your app is launched again then right from the `DidFinishLaunching` you can `startLocationUpdates`.

If your app was **suspended** or for some reason still in the **background** you would only get the `didExitRegion` callback. And AFIAK from the callback you're not able to `startUpdateLocations`. This is a very *vague* text from WWDC.

> Finally, you *must* start your location updates while in the
>   foreground. If you don’t start your updates in the foreground, you
>   won’t get this special behavior. So what happens if you do start your
>   updates in the background? Well, first off, your app will probably
>   need AlwaysAuthorization since your app won’t be considered in use at
>   that time. Furthermore, Core Location *won’t* take any action to
>   ensure your app continues to run. So if you have background runtime
>   for some reason, and you decide to start a location session, you
>   **might** get some updates, but you **might** also get suspended before you receive all the information you had hoped to receive.
>
> <sub>[WWDC 2016: Session 716](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/716/?time=390)</sub>

I don't know why Apple is saying might...it could be something that varies based on battery/cell coverage/ usage patterns / iOS version. It's obviously something they don't want us developers know how. They want to force us to go for other ways.

The only way for you to get your app into terminated state is either if you user manually kills the app or you wait for a very very long time ie wait for any or all other background tasks to finish + then once app is suspended **wait** for it to become terminated and then exit the region to launch app and be able to start tracking Locations